# What to do when no work in office?

Tags: software-industry

I am working in software firm since 1 year. For last 3 months we dont have much work to do.

So the first thing comes to my mind every morning when I come to office is, what to do today?

Please suggest some interesting thing which will help me to improve my knowledge.

Comment: Have you looked at what tests you have?  Have you looked at the logs on the servers to see if any errors are occurring?  Have you looked at what refactoring may make sense to do on the code?  There's a few ideas for you.

Comment: Have you tried plants v Zombies?

Comment: Increasing test coverage is always welcome.

Answer (score 8):

1. Is the documentation up to date?
2. Do you have automated tests for all features?
3. Are there new version of your dependecies?

   1. Would updating increse the stabilty / security ?
   2. will your code work with the new version?
4. Check the news for your plaform / kind of software?

   1. Try to learn a new skill
   2. Take notes of your sources and mistakes
   3. Once you have a good understanding of whatever you learned write about you experiences so others do not have to repeat your mistakes